# Shorten statement in SQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL query as below

```
SELECT sum(case WHEN cardinality(male) <= 0  and native='latin' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end ) AS males,
       sum(case WHEN native='latin' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS  total, sum(case WHEN cardinality(male) <= 0  and native='latin' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end )*sum(case WHEN native='latin' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as percent
FROM continent
WHERE(country = 'US');
```

I want to reduce statement `sum(case WHEN cardinality(male) <= 0  and native='US' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end ) * sum(case WHEN native='latin' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) to something like (males * total)`. Is there any way?

Comment: What is cardinality()? Also the expressions `sum(case WHEN cardinality(male) <= 0  and native='US' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end )` and `sum(case WHEN native='latin' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end)` are not the same as `males` and `total`.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend preparing your data a bit before the final summations. That way it becomes more readable. Do this by using a WITH before the main SELECT like this:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT
    CASE WHEN cardinality(male) <= 0  and native='latin' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end males,
    CASE WHEN native='US'                                THEN 1 ELSE 0 end total,
    CASE WHEN cardinality(male) <= 0  and native='US'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 end us,
    CASE WHEN native='latin'                             THEN 1 ELSE 0 end latin
  FROM continent WHERE country='US'
)
SELECT
  sum(males) males,
  sum(total) total,
  sum(us) * sum(latin) percent
FROM data;
```

A WITH statement is also called common table expressions (CTEs) and it creates sort of a temporary VIEW for your SELECT. Most databases support it in 2020, not sure about MySQL but I think so. (Not sure what kind of percent you get by multiplying like this)

Answer (score 1):

In MySql Boolean expressions are evaluated as `1` for `true` or `0` for `false`, so your query can be simplified to:

```
SELECT sum(cardinality(male) <= 0 and native='latin') AS males,
       sum(native='latin') AS  total, 
       sum(cardinality(male) <= 0 and native='latin') * sum(native='latin') AS percent
FROM continent
WHERE country = 'US';
```

If you use a subquery that returns `males` and `total` then you can return `percent` as their product:

```
SELECT males, total, males * total AS percent
FROM (
  SELECT sum(cardinality(male) <= 0 and native='latin') AS males,
         sum(native='latin') AS  total
  FROM continent
  WHERE country = 'US'
) t
```